# З'явився бот, що повідомляє електроною поштою про нові запитання

Tags: discussion

Щоб отримувати сповіщення про нові запитання у вашу електронну поштову скриньку, надішліть повідомлення з темою/заголовком `S` (одна англійська літера, велика чи мала — неважливо, це від англ. слова *subscribe*) на адресу [image: U K R S E точка B O T равлик G M A I L точка C O M]
Сповіщення надходитимуть саме з цієї адреси (у разі необхідності, внесіть її в білий список).
Аналогічно, щоб перестати отримувати сповіщення, надішліть повідомлення з темою/заголовком `U` (від англійського *unsubscribe*).
<sub>Такі вхідні повідомлення-команди обробляються з інтервалом приблизно 1 година, тому не очікуйте на миттєву реакцію. У разі вдалого підключення/відключення вам десь через годину прийде відповідь. У разі невдалої команди ніяких відповідей не буде.</sub>

Якщо ви підключитеся, то бот намагатиметься надсилати вам спровіщення приблизно раз на годину. Діє він так: якщо протягом останньої години не з'явилося жодного нового запитання, то він нічого не надсилає; якщо протягом години з'явилося одне запитання, то він надсилає лист із назвою цього запитання в темі повідомлення й текстом у самому повідомленні; якщо з'явилося декілька запитань, то він всіх їх надсилає одним листом, у темі якого буде зазначена їхня кількість. На відміну від бота для Facebook, цей ніяк не реагує на нові відповіді чи оновлення запитань/відповідей — суто нові запитання.

Поради й пропозиції приймаються. У разі якихось технічних питань чи проблем теж можна писати сюди. У самого Stack Exchange, власне, теж є вбудована можливість надсилати новини — але раз на тиждень. А цей бот призначений для майже моментального сповіщення про нові запитання (інтервал «1 година» наразі через технічні причини, в майбутньому, можливо, його буде скорочено).

Comment: Кльово, але — чим це рішення краще ніж стандартний RSS ([аґреґаторів — море](https://www.google.com/search?q=rss+reader)) + RSS-to-email боти ([яких теж — море](https://www.google.com/search?q=rss+to+email))? Особливо, якщо він не реагує на нові відповіді. Я весь Стек читаю через RSS, і для мене суттєвою проблемою є те, що коли я бачу цікаві запитання, вони зазвичай «голі», без відповідей, які, можливо, могли б бути мені цікавими.

Comment: @bytebuster, мабуть, нічим. Зроблено, перш за все, задля вивчення Scala. Дякую за нагадування про RSS.